# Wrong value inserted in table from php array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

code for scraping from a site :

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
$url = 'http://www.indianrail.gov.in/mail_express_trn_list.html';
$ch = curl_init($url);

set_time_limit(600);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $result;
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$dom    = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');  
$dom->loadHTML($result);
if($dom)
{
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


        $q = '///*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " table_border ")]/tr';


        $nodes = $xpath->query($q);
        foreach($nodes as $tr){ // DOMNodesList implements traversable 
            echo "<br>";
            $tds = $tr->childNodes;
            $i = 0;
            foreach($tds as $td){
                $arr[$i]=$td->nodeValue;
                $i++;
            }
            var_dump($arr);
            //echo"<br><=====><br>";
            //echo ""
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `irl`.`trains` (`TrainNo`, `TrainName`, `Origin`, `DepartureTime`, `Destination`, `ArrivalTime`) 
                                VALUES ('$arr[0]', '$arr[1]', '$arr[2]', '$arr[3]', '$arr[4]', '$arr[5]');") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        }

}
else
echo "invalid DOMDocument <br>";
```

this inserts '0's in the first position(TrainNo.) in the database, even though arr[0] contains the right values(I checked the var_dump($arr) ), what is going on ? arr[] is populated with the right values in each iteration., `database field is int with size 8`

**changing field to varchar does fix it**, but if datatyoe is the problem , why does the first row(train number 2696) get inserted correctly

example:

```
arr[0]=> 09705
arr[1]=>JP DEE AC EXP 
arr[2]=>JAIPUR 
arr[3]=>07:55
arr[4]=>DELHI S ROHILLA    
arr[5]=>13:20
```

Ignore the first row, it contains the table headers, so it is understandble that it contains 0:0 for time, and 0 for train number., but the rows below it should be fine, in the highlighted row first position should have been 9705, but it holds 0 :
EDIT: including screenshots for convenience :
screenshots of var_dump of $arr in loop, followed by db rows in phpmyadmin :
[image: var_dump($arr)]

[image: screenie of db rows]

Comment: How did you achieved that it is wrongly inserted in db? What is your actual problem. You need to be more specific

Comment: what is datatype of 'TrainNo' column?

Comment: it is int, incidentally it inserts one row correctly, then all others wrong even though `arr` contains the right value

Comment: Please read the question completely, I have explained the problem clearly enough and mentioned that it is `int(8)`.

Comment: You should use prepared statement, since you are not sure about the consistency of data in the website (what about a string containing the `'` character ?). See my answer for the actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `$arr[0]` variable, from your screenshot, there is a space before the integer value `09705`. Try an `intval($arr[0])` if it's an integer type in your database.

If you want to preserve the leading 0, you must change your type to VARCHAR for this column, and insert with `trim($arr[0])` to delete the space character anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try `trim($arr[0]);` before inserting in db.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around $arr[0] in your query? and do this in your code :

```
if ($i > 0) {
$arr[$i]=$td->nodeValue;
}
else {
 $arr[$i]=intval($td->nodeValue);
}
```

because **nodeValue** is always of type **String** .

Something is strange, your first insert have been converted to string(6), and the others to string(8). Have you modified your code between ?